# SPARQL: remove duplicated attributes

Tags: duplicates, sparql

I coudln't find the answer for this question so I am opening a new one. I have an RDF dataset like this:

```
<dc:Terminal rdf:ID="_1A5C">
<dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode rdf:resource="#_CN1"></dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode>
<dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode rdf:resource="#_CN2"></dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode>
<dc:Object.description>DESC</dc:Object.description>
<dc:Object.name>T1</dc:Object.name>
<dc:Equipment rdf:resource="#_E8455C1C0A63"></dc:Equipment>
</dc:Terminal>
```

...and I need to distinguish between the attributes `dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode`. For example to rename it to **`dc:Attribute1`** (containing `CN1` in this example) and **`dc:Attribute2`** (containing `CN2` in this example).

But of course when I query for `dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode`, it will always select both of them.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove duplicates in sparql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348328/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-sparql-query)

Comment: @JcDenton86 I have read that also but I have rdf:resource and didn't find anything useful there.

Comment: Why does it not work to use LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by using a Turtle text serialization of your triples.  This makes it much easier to understand the triples:

```
:_1A5C
  rdf:type dc:Terminal ;
  dc:Equipment <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_E8455C1C0A63> ;
  <http://example.org/file1#Object.description> "DESC" ;
  <http://example.org/file1#Object.name> "T1" ;
  <http://example.org/file1#Terminal.ConnectivityNode> <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN1> ;
  <http://example.org/file1#Terminal.ConnectivityNode> <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN2> .
```

If these are specific requirements, then you could use a brute-force query.  Here's one for the `<http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN2>` value:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://example.org/so#>
DELETE {
    :_1A5C ?p <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN2> .
}
INSERT {
   :_1A5C dc:Attribute2 <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN2> .
}
WHERE {
   :_1A5C ?p <http://marklogic.icap.org/unnamed#_CN2> .
}
```

Or you could generalize this per the examples you gave:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://example.org/so#>
DELETE {
   :_1A5C ?p ?o
}
INSERT {
   :_1A5C ?newProp ?o
}
WHERE {
   :_1A5C ?p ?o .
   BIND(xsd:string(?o) AS ?objStr)
   # get the end char to append to the new property, e.g. '_CN1' ==> 'Attribute1'
   BIND(SUBSTR(?objStr, (STRLEN(?objStr))) AS ?endChar)
   BIND(IRI(CONCAT("http://example.org/so#Attribute", ?endChar)) AS ?newProp)
   FILTER CONTAINS(xsd:string(?o), "_CN")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the attribute value is not always ending with _CN1 or _CN2 it waas only an example. It is a mix of some letters and numbers and only thing that is common is the attribute name and attribute value length.

Comment: OK, as long as there us some regularity to the name then `SUBSTR` and other SPARQL string functions should be able to get the job done.

Comment: Hi Scot, can you explain further? It is not a problem to use SUBSTR but I cant just select one of the two attributes, since when I **query** for dc:Terminal.ConnectivityNode it will always select both.

Comment: The `?objStr` is bound for each match to the query.  So if you have x:_CN1 and x:CN2, then you will get two matches.  Per the `INSERT` statement, two triples will be created with properties named  `dc:Attribute1` and `dc:Attribute2`, respectively, and insert them into your graph.